# How can I select all relations automatically in Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a rather big number of classes related to each other via various relations (OneToOne, OneToMany, ManyToOne as well as Class- and Joined Inheritance which in turn again have multiple relations.

When I want to select all of a parent class via a simple `->findAll()`, I get around 10 extra queries per Entity. I can reduce this number by a limited extend by unsing the a QueryBuilder with `->leftJoin()` and `->addSelect()`. Some relations do not join because [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496621/doctrine-dql-class-table-inheritance-and-access-to-subclass-fields). Still, it gets a pretty nasty long list of `addSelect()`s. Is there a way to join and select all relations automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automatical join can be achieved by setting the fetch-mode of the associations to eager (e.g. on ManyToOne:

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cart", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER")
 */
```

, see [the docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytoone))

To set the fetch mode programatically, refer to [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420175/how-to-retrieve-an-entity-with-all-of-its-associations-using-entitymanager-in-do).

Answer (score 0):

Try using "JoinTable" or "JoinColumn"

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#jointable

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I am already using JoinTable as well as JoinColumn, depending on the Entity